# What does mysqld_safe do in my.cnf?

Tags: mysql

Below is my MySQL config file.  I am trying to understand how it works.  What is the point of `[mysqld_safe]`?  Hasn't `[mysqld]` already start MySQL?  Why is the log-error and pid-file settings after it?

```
[mysqld]
# Settings user and group are ignored when systemd is used (fedora >= 15).
# If you need to run mysqld under different user or group, 
# customize your systemd unit file for mysqld according to the
# instructions in http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd
user=mysql

datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

# Semisynchronous Replication
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-semisync.html
# uncomment next line on MASTER
;plugin-load=rpl_semi_sync_master=semisync_master.so
# uncomment next line on SLAVE
;plugin-load=rpl_semi_sync_slave=semisync_slave.so

# Others options for Semisynchronous Replication
;rpl_semi_sync_master_enabled=1
;rpl_semi_sync_master_timeout=10
;rpl_semi_sync_slave_enabled=1

# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/performance-schema.html
;performance_schema

innodb_strict_mode=on
sql_mode=TRADITIONAL
;sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_general_ci

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can start MySQL server using either `mysqld` or `mysqld_safe`. `mysqld_safe` may itself try to execute `mysqld` but also may not. See the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqld-safe.html) (*the first result in Google for* mysqld_safe, *btw*):

> mysqld_safe is the recommended way to start a mysqld server on Unix and NetWare. mysqld_safe adds some safety features such as restarting the server when an error occurs and logging runtime information to an error log file. NetWare-specific behaviors are listed later in this section.

Section `[mysqld_safe]` in the configuration file is for settings applied when you use `mysqld_safe` to start MySQL server instead of `mysqld`.

Comment: Thanks Mifeet.  Yes, I looked at the documentation you referenced before posting this question.  I didn't understand that Section `[mysqld_safe]` is for settings applied when I use `mysqld_safe` to start MySQL.  Does this mean that the other settings under `[mysqld]` don't apply why MySQL is started using `mysqld_safe`?  Why does adding logging under `[mysqld]` result in an error?

Comment: Upon further reading, `mysqld_safe reads all options from the [mysqld], [server], and [mysqld_safe] sections in option files`.  What still confuses me is that I appear to have `log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log` even when started normally.

Comment: @user1032531 Isn't it the default value? Have you tried setting a different value for `log-error` in `[mysqld_safe]`? What error you you mean?

Comment: Sorry, didn't explain.  Yes, I tried different values for `log-error`, and it created a new log file of that name.  I was trying to log all transactions, so I added `log=/var/log/mysqld_all.log`  If directly under `[mysqld]`, I get `File /var/log/mysqld_all.log not found (Errocode: 13)`

Comment: Ah, I guess the file needs to exist first!  Still don't understand why I still have error logging even if I start MySQL using `/etc/init.d/mysqld start` since `log=/var/log/mysqld_all.log` is under [mysqld_safe].

Comment: @Mifeet,If I set `pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld22.pid` under `[mysqld_safe]`,and use `mysqld` to start. Is this `pid` applied?